# How to calculate the difference between two file lists

Tags: command-line-interface, ksh, aix

On AIX i am using ksh.
I have two file lists created with `find . -newer file1 > list1`  and `find . -newer file2 > list2`.

How can I now get a difference of those two lists?

list1:

```
.
./iosrv_0.in.gz
./iosrv_0.out.gz
./iosrv_6.err.gz
./iosrv_6.in.gz
```

list 2:

```
.
./iosrv_0.in.gz
./iosrv_0.out.gz
```

resulting list should be this:

```
./iosrv_6.err.gz
./iosrv_6.in.gz
```

I was thinking about grep and diff. I did not find a way to achieve that with `grep -v`. And diff does require heavy manipulation of its output to achieve demanded result.

What do I miss here?

Note: I cannot target any file extension or the like. The file lists will be completely generic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, sometimes you find the answer after asking...

my solution is this:

`comm -1 -3 list1 list2`

The `-1` excludes lines that are only in **list1**, and the `-3` excludes lines that are in both. Thus only the lines exclusively in **list2** are output...

Comment: fwiw, you can also combine the flags into `comm -13 list1 list2`